# How to execute simple query of Big Query table from Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble figuring out how to execute a simple delete query against a Big Query Table from an app script function.  The query works when executing from the Big Query console.
The error is coming back as : Unrecognized name: for the timestamp value I'm trying to pass in to string query.

The  BigQuery api is loaded into app script as I can execute  a simple select query with no parameter.

```
function RemoveRoles()
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Config");
   var value = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();

  const projectId = 'xxxxx-346316';

  const request = {
       
    query: 'delete FROM `xxxxx-346316.Feedback.Role`  where `Time` < `' + value + '`;', 
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  let queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  const jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  let sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);



}
}
```

**GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Unrecognized name: `2022-03-04 18:28:00` at [1:58]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
  const request = {
       
    query: 'delete FROM `xxxxx-346316.Feedback.Role`  where `Time` < `' + value + '`;', 
    useLegacySql: false
  };
```

with

```
  const request = {
       
    query: 'delete FROM `xxxxx-346316.Feedback.Role`  where `Time` < "' + value + '";', 
    useLegacySql: false
  };
```

Comment: Thank so much! Fixed it. I feel like I tried that this syntax along with many other variations but I guess not.